# Rendering and skipping to next column with vue.js for loop

Tags: vue.js

I have 15 records in my item. I want to render them in such a way that my three column should reflect and limit to 15 unique items. If it was one column then it would have not been an issue but here it has three column. So basically it should be something like render 5 column then skip to the next column and render 5 again and so. I can accomplish this by creating 3 v-for loops and render it but this is complicating a bit. Is there anything in which I can render, stop, render.

```
<div id="mylist" class="ui grid" v-for="(item, index) in infox">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="ui link list">
            <a class="item">{{needtorender}}</a>
            <a class="item">{{needtorender}}</a>
            <a class="item">{{needtorender}}</a>
            <a class="item">{{needtorender}}</a>
            <a class="item">{{needtorender}}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="ui link list">
            <a class="item">{{needtorender}}</a>
            <a class="item">{{needtorender}}</a>
            <a class="item">{{needtorender}}</a>
            <a class="item">{{needtorender}}</a>
            <a class="item">{{needtorender}} >></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="ui link list">
            <a class="item">{{needtorender}}</a>
            <a class="item">{{needtorender}}</a>
            <a class="item">{{needtorender}}</a>
            <a class="item">{{needtorender}}</a>
            <a class="item">{{needtorender}}></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So for example, if i have 6 airlines.
JetAirways, Emirates, Lufthansa, Swiss, Aeroflot, Finnair. Then it should be something as below

```
<div id="mylist" class="ui grid" v-for="(item, index) in infox">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="ui link list">
            <a class="item">JetAirways</a>
            <a class="item">Emirates</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="ui link list">
            <a class="item">Lufthansa</a>
            <a class="item">Swiss</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="ui link list">
            <a class="item">Aeroflot</a>
            <a class="item">Finnair</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sorry if this question feels like too easy to solve. I am new to vue.js

Comment: how do the columns overflow? what is the expected behavior given an N amount of items? how are the items sorted between columns? vertically, horizontally?

Comment: @PabloAlbornoz, it does not matter how column are sorted. I am not worried about how it is being displayed. I am just trying to find the logic on how we can stop a for loop after 5 count in first column and resume from the next column. I have also given an example on how my airlines should render. Basically that example is the desired result.

Comment: ok then: your example is lacking a few edge cases: if your columns are always the same length, what happens when the number of items is not divisible by three? (2, 8, 11...), will the number of columns ever be the same?

Comment: @PabloAlbornoz my column will always be 3 with 5 items on each, if that is what you want to know. My column will never increase or decrease. So if I have 15 airlines then it should render once on all the three column with 5 items each.

Comment: @PabloAlbornoz, my airlines will not exceed more than 15

Answer (score 0):

I would compute the data you want to render in a computed property then iterate over it in your template. 
This can be done in a few ways. I would recommend using lodash `difference` and `unique` you can create a single array with unique value and then filter your existing elements if they are not in the unique element array.